# BASH command on remote workstation is returning results from source machine, not the remote one

Tags: bash, routes, ssh, scope, ip

As a learning project, I'm writing a little BASH script that will list various elements of two workstations.  It should compare the machine the script is executed on and one passed to the script.

In part of the script, I want to get the active NICs MAC address from both workstations.

The commands I am using currently, are returning results from just the local machine and not the one that is being ssh'd to.

I have other parts of the compare script working, so I know the concept works, but I think I have issues embedding commands inside of other commands.

On the local machine, I can do this to identify the live network port and gets its MAC address:

```
cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address
```

but if I want to get the active MAC of a remote workstation (and store the result in a variable), the ip route command seems be evaluated on the source workstation and not on the remote machine.

```
rMAC=$(ssh $remotehostname "cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address")
```

is there a way to make the ssh'd command execute everything on the remote host and just return back the string I want?

Comment: Escape the command substition as `\$(ip ..)` to avoid being expanded *before* ssh,

Comment: Thanks for your time - sadly not quite working for me.
without the backslash - Its getting the wrong device, 
ssh rook "cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address"
cat: /sys/class/net/enp2s0/address: No such file or directory
but with the backslash, I'm getting a new error
ssh rook "cat /sys/class/net/\$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address"
Illegal variable name.

Comment: You may have a problem in quotings anyway. Single quotes and double quotes are not
interoperable in bash. Please follow the suggestion by Gordon Davisson.

Comment: @tshiono: In this case, this is not a problem. The single quotes are within `$(...)`, which defines a new nesting level.  Hence, `awk` does see a `$5`.

Comment: I think Gordon may have withdrawn his answer - at least, I'm not seeing it so not too sure what was offered.  I tried another whole method of tackling this using << 'EOF' and spliting things out.  This worked ok in a bash terminal, but when I put it into my script, I got a whole new error on some hosts, and just a script hang on others.